i am facing a issue during use flet with python to build a windows app, ContainerTapEvent is not working for me
i trying to use a Container, contain a image, and i want to achieve when user click the iamge, my app can   can obtain the coordinates of where the image was clicked.
i had try useing following parameter：
ContainerTapEvent.global_x
ContainerTapEvent.local_x
TapEvent.global_x
TapEvent.local_x
all these parameter is not working for me
here is my code
import flet as ft

def main(page: ft.Page):
    page.vertical_alignment = ft.MainAxisAlignment.CENTER
    page.horizontal_alignment = ft.CrossAxisAlignment.CENTER

    t1 = ft.Text()
    t2 = ft.Text()

    def container_click(e: ft.ContainerTapEvent):
        t1.value = f"local_x: {e.local_x}\nlocal_y: {e.local_y}"
        t2.value = f"global_x: {e.global_x}\nglobal_y: {e.global_y}"
        t.update()

    page.add(
        ft.Column(
            [
                ft.Container(
                    content=ft.Text("Clickable inside container"),
                    alignment=ft.alignment.center,
                    bgcolor=ft.colors.GREEN_200,
                    width=200,
                    height=200,
                    border_radius=10,
                    on_click=container_click,
                ),
                t1,
                t2,
            ],
            horizontal_alignment=ft.CrossAxisAlignment.CENTER,
        ),
    )

ft.app(target=main)

